# R: two item 100% stacked bar chart, percentages not showing correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My intention is to plot to items into same stacked bar chart as separate bars. The data frame looks like this, and the percentages are correct there.

[image]

But the proportions in the bars do not go according to the percentages. Can you find the flaw in my code?
[image]

```
plot_data %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = value),
           position = 'fill',
           width = 0.30)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = '% of responders',
                     breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.2),
                     minor_breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1),
                     labels = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 20),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab( element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('red', 'blue', 'green'),
    labels = c(
      'Yes',
      'No',
      'Maybe'
    ),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title = 'Answer')
  ) + theme(text = element_text(size = 12), 
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = margin(t = 150, r =  30, b = 20, l = 0),
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'lightgrey'),
            axis.text.y = element_text(
              size = 12,
              face = 'plain',
              hjust = 0
            )) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 50)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)
    str_wrap(x, width = 20))
```

My data:

```
plot_data <- structure(list(variable = c("Question 1", "Question 1", "Question 1", 
"Question 2", "Question 2", "Question 2"), value = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), n = c(102L, 27L, 18L, 78L, 62L, 7L), pct = c(0.693877551020408, 
0.183673469387755, 0.122448979591837, 0.530612244897959, 0.421768707482993, 
0.0476190476190476)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    variable = c("Question 1", "Question 2"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:3, 4:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: geom_bar uses a count (if discrete) or summation of values (if continuous) as y. The solution is to use`geom_bar(stat = "identity")`, for which exists the alias or shorthand `geom_col`. You will then need to pass a y value. This is how quinten's answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the pct values as `y` `aes` with `geom_col` and to have an percentage y-axis you could use the `percent` function from `scales` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
plot_data %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = variable)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = value, y = pct),
           position = 'fill',
           width = 0.30)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab( element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('red', 'blue', 'green'),
    labels = c(
      'Yes',
      'No',
      'Maybe'
    ),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title = 'Answer')
  ) + theme(text = element_text(size = 12), 
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
            panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'lightgrey'),
            axis.text.y = element_text(
              size = 12,
              face = 'plain',
              hjust = 0
            )) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 50)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)
    str_wrap(x, width = 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>